# Angular UI Bootstrap Datapicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, iso8601

this is my base code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PuzsgIgpRKUwuXbyIMSq?p=preview.

I want to visualize the datepicker popup only on button click and not on input focus.

Moreover the data in the input element should be visualized as dd/MM/yyyy and this is a problem because it can't be parsed as Date since it is not a ISO 8601 allowed format.

Of course, when a correct date is inserted in the input element it should be reflected in the datepicker and when a date is selected in the datepicker it should be put in the input element (as it is shown in the example plunker) in the dd/MM/yyyy format (in the plunker the format is yyyy-MM-dd).

Thanks in advance,

Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your AngularJS and Angular-UI references and you should see that fixed.

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/08AHp5pJ0bUGnCXYkoKO?p=preview

Comment: Yes, the Q was related to older versions of both AngularJS and UI. Now it is possible to do want I wanted 8 months ago :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.